# Tcp protocol prefix the length of message

Tags: c++, node.js

I'm trying to prefix the length of message so its 4 bytes and use big-endian in C++, but i don't understand how to do that. In Node.JS i'm doing it like that:

```
var buffer = new Buffer("HELLO WORLD");

 //create a buffer with +4 bytes
var consolidatedBuffer = new Buffer(4 + buffer.length);

 //write at the beginning of the buffer, the total size
consolidatedBuffer.writeInt32BE(buffer.length, 0);

 //Copy the message buffer to the consolidated buffer at position 4  (after the 4 bytes about the size)

 buffer.copy(consolidatedBuffer, 4);
```

i'm trying to achieve the same result in C++, but don't know how to do the same, can someone please show me how that is done in C++? the result should be string byte array

I'm doing that on Mac:

```
 std::string data = "HELLO WORLD";

 uint32_t length = htonl( data.length() );

 std::string payload;

 payload.append(std::to_string(length));

 payload.append(data);
```

Comment: Please show the C++ code you have tried. This will help us understand which library you are using (if using any) and how.

Comment: Sure, i updated it :) please take look

Comment: No sure  what actually confuses you. Do you know the basics of working with buffers in C++?

Comment: I'm not doing it right, tried to decode in JS, but it looked wrong..

Comment: "I'm not doing it right" "it looked wrong" "don't know how to do the same" Sorry these are not valid problem statements.

Comment: mysterious ways, different views.. each to it own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this would be something like

```
std::vector<char> pack(const std::string& str) {
      const uint32_t sz = str.size();
      const uint32_t n_sz = htonl(sz);
      std::vector<char> result(sizeof(sz) + sz);
      memcpy(result.data(), &n_sz, sizeof(n_sz));
      memcpy(result.data() + sizeof(sz), str.data(), sz);
      return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain which line use " big-endian "  in the code ? and i'm getting warning: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'const uint32_t' (aka 'const unsigned int')

Comment: const uint32_t sz = str.size(); is thowing warning: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'const uint32_t' (aka 'const unsigned int')

Comment: @HansHansen, I missed big endian part, added it now. Warning is here because size of the string is 64bit in your platform, but you are using 32bit sizes in the app. You can silence it by doing explicit cast `...sz = static_cast<uint32_t>(str.size())`

Comment: That give sense, the code is well written so i understand it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Would you be able to show me how to unpack that in C++ again please ?? this will allow me to fully be sure i'm doing it right

Comment: @HansHansen same way. I leave it to your as an exercise. If you struggle, ask a separate question (do not forget to post your code, aka what you tried so far!)